# Can I have the shape information of the shared variable in theano?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, theano, deep-learning

It seems that variable.shape would notify me that

```
AttributeError: 'SharedVariable' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

while theano.tensor.shape(variable) will return me a `shape.0`

I am really confused why can't I get a shape information on that? The same problem occurs when I want to get the shape information of a symbolic variable. It is just so weird.

```
x = T.matrix('x')   # the data is presented as rasterized images
y = T.ivector('y')  # the labels are presented as 1D vector of
                        # [int] labels

layer0_input = x.reshape((batch_size, 1, 28, 28))
```

In the example above, the x (symbolic variable) has been reshaped to some shape, if would not make sense to me if I can't retrieve its shape information while could still assigning it new shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error is probably due to the fact that you tried to evaluate the `shape` property on the data type `SharedVariable`, not on an actual shared variable.

Otherwise, obtaining `shape.0` is completely normal: This is a symbolic expression representing the shape, which is a priori unknown. As soon as you evaluate with data, you will see the shape:

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as T
import numpy as np
s = theano.shared(np.arange(2 * 3 * 5).reshape(2, 3, 5))
print(s.shape)  # gives you shape.0
print(s.shape.eval())  # gives you an array containing 2, 3, 5

a = T.tensor3()
print(a.shape)  # gives you shape.0
print(a.shape.eval({a: np.arange(2 * 3 * 5).reshape(2, 3, 5).astype(theano.config.floatX)}))  # gives 2, 3, 5
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you view another question of me?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36312253/why-cant-i-evaluate-the-reshaped-tensorvariable-in-theano