# Why can't I evaluate the reshaped tensorvariable in theano?

Tags: python, numpy, theano, deep-learning

Why can't I evaluate the reshaped tensorvariable through the code I wrote below?

```
from theano import shared
from theano import tensor as T
import numpy

x = T.matrix('x') # the input data

# input = (nImages, nChannel(nFeatureMaps), nDim1, nDim2, nDim3)

layer1_input = T.reshape(x, xTrain.shape, ndim=5)
layer1_input.eval({x:xTrain})
```

Since I have reshape the tensorvariable x, and pass a numpy array of same dimension to it, it simply reports,

> TypeError: ('Bad input argument to theano function with name
>   ":17"  at index 0(0-based)', 'Wrong
>   number of dimensions: expected 2, got 5 with shape (2592, 1, 51, 61,
>   23).')

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is because you are using `matrix` (two dimensional) as data type of `x` that receive a five dimensional input `xTrain`. As said [here](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#custom-tensor-types), for five dimensional input, you should create a custom data type.

sample code:

```
from theano import tensor as T
import numpy as np
xTrain = np.random.rand(1,1,2,3,3).astype('float32')

dtensor5 = T.TensorType('float32', (False,)*5)
x = dtensor5('x')

layer1_input = x
print layer1_input.eval({x:xTrain})
```

and about

> Since I have reshape the tensorvariable x, and pass a numpy array of
>   same dimension to it

I think what actually happen is variable `x` recieve the input first (raise an error) and then you reshape it for `layer1_input`

Comment: I was thinking in that way and my program seems to stuck on that eval() part. If we could always declare a customized tensortype, why can we still reshape them to a higher dimension as the tutorial said (at least it seems to be so).

Comment: I've update my answer. what kind of "stuck"? reshape could be use like in your code, `layer1_input` will five dimensional (without declare first) while `x` is two dimensional tensor variable